# HTML saves data in Access?

Tags: javascript, php, html, database, ms-access

I have a problem, but lets know what I have now.

**What I have:**

• DB File in ACCESS with 100+ lines of data.

• HTML webpage with inputs like the ACCESS file.

• Homemade dedicated server (HDS)

The DB file is saved in my HDS, and my webpage is saved in the same directory (nothing here is hosted in a external server).

**What i need to do:**

• DB file receives the HTML input values and save.

• HTML receives warnings from dates of the data inside DB.

Let's think i have three inputs, same for DB and HTML, and they are called: Name, Telephone, Date. I want to write the name in the HTML input, the telephone and the date, and it needs to save those information in the DB that has the same inputs. When the due date is near the current date, that's where the warning would appear in the HTML page.

**Obs.: This question is just for academical purposes and personal growth, as I identify a lot with web programming area.**

Comment: You would connect to the database with PHP.....

Comment: It's not really clear what you actually asking here...

Comment: Bulk, i have a input called Name, and i have in Access a column called Name. When i add something in my input (in the HTML page) and hit the Save Button, it needs to save in the DB column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty much what MySQL is made for. Check out [this](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) reference. It won't be an access database, but you can import preexisting data if you need to. Your post says that this is academic, though, so you should really make the switch. Most web hosts come with databases. Even some free web hosts will let you have one database.

Comment: Thanks for this advice, Pocketg! I'm working on it now.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on same situation so my technique is some thing like this

- Using HTML for front end
- Using VBScript for getting values from HTML
- Using Access Database to save data

for that i am using form tag in html like

`<form id="registerform" name="registerform" action="register-your-self.asp" method="post">`

when we click on submit it calls `register-your-self.asp` file and in this file I am using logic to get all values from HTML tags and save them in Access database

```
    if Request.Form("form_title") <> "" Then
        Title = Request.Form("form_title")
        'response.Write("<br/> Title :" &Title)
    end if
```

In this `form_title` is name / id of HTML tag